# Pergunta fechada sem critério aparente

Tags: debate

fiz uma pergunta aparentemente simples porém que não encontrei uma solução em lugar nenhum.
Eu pensei encontrar ao menos uma oportunidade aqui no Stack mas a pergunta foi fechada em menos de 15 minutos, eu expus o máximo o que precisava fazer e de forma simples, isso deixa uma uma enorme frustração em de certa forma "perder" tempo elaborando a questão para que fique de forma legível e de facil entendimento para ser fechada tão rapidamente. Espero conseguir resolver essa questão.

Comment: A conversa ficou longa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123203/discussion-on-question-by-jose-roberto-juliana-pergunta-fechada-sem-criterio-apa) - basta clicar no link pra ler ou prosseguir. Sobre a pergunta, pode [edit] a qualquer momento e linkar os posts apropriados que tenham relação com o que alega.